# returning primitives via .andReturn(Boolean arg0) with Powermock

Tags: java, junit, powermock

I keep getting a

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: incompatible return value type
```

when I run my test. The line in questions seems to be:

```
expect(userName.contains("@")).andReturn(false);
```

In my code, I'm checking to see if a string (in this case, userName) contains an "@" symbol. In my test, I want to return false so that I can test particular behaviour. The return type expected for the method seems to be 'Boolean arg0', however from the examples I've seen online it looks like you should be able to pass back a primitive type.

Is this a situation of primitives vs Objects? And if so, is it possible to pass a primitive in .andReturn() with Powermock?

Thanks

Comment: You can try returning `new Boolean(false)`

Comment: `expect(userName.contains("@")).andReturn(new Boolean(false)); ` yields the same error.

Comment: I hope you are calling `addMockedMethod` for the method you are setting the expectation for.

Comment: Which raises a good point - can we see a bit more of what's going on? And can you be specific as to whether you are using EasyMock or Mockito? Looks like EasyMock, but best to be sure.

Comment: @AmyPond Please respond to the comments above

Comment: @user2004685 I had not used the 'addMockedMethod' for the 'contains' String method as I had (possibly incorrectly) assumed that the 'contains' method could be run without being mocked. I'm currently doing some more reading on powermock and unit testing as I may need to start there.